# designer workflow not sending emails to user in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am configuring a workflow in SharePoint Designer to send email when status is changed to draft or pending authorization. I want to send mail .
so when I am changing status in this url(`http://abcd:1111/_layouts/15/wrksetng.aspx?List=%7B38234571-368D-4127-A3BE-1C75C202C804%7D`) the workflow inprogress it displaying some time for 1 and after some time inprogress is becomes 0. means the workflow is running, but the emails are not sending.
Where can I see the workflow log details in SharePoint 2013. I want to see workflow log details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event Viewer, but:

> By default the Analytic and debug log for workflow manager is
>   disabled. You can enable the event viewer and see what’s going on
>   under the hood. You can find out details on how to enable the event
>   viewer in [Analyzing Workflow Management Logs in Workflow Manager
>   1.0](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193526)

Also more information about [Debugging SharePoint Server 2013 workflows here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn508412.aspx)